# postgresql ERROR: syntax error at or near "CONCAT"

Tags: postgresql

i am trying to fetch users list who older than and between 20 to 60 minute randomly. here is my query

```
SELECT * 
FROM  t_users 
WHERE create_time <= NOW() -  INTERVAL CONCAT(floor(random()* (60-20 + 1) + 20),' minutes');
```

it's giving me error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CONCAT"`

Comment: this would be valid in MySQL but not in PostgreSQL world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `concat()` like that to create an interval. The easiest solution is to use `make_interval`:

```
WHERE create_time <= NOW() - make_interval(mins => (floor(random()* (60-20 + 1) + 20))::int )
```